# Control buttons in an images slideshow doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i made slideshows for my artwork website and one of them magically doesn't work.

I couldn't figure it out. I hope i can use your help

```js
var slideIndex = [1,1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 700px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.prev1, .next1 {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 7px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
  }

    .next1 {
        right: 195px;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      }
      .prev1 {
          left: 180px;
      }


      .prev1:hover, .next1:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      }
.prev2, .next2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1244px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}
.next2 {
    left: 590px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  .prev2 {
      left: 530px;
  }


  .prev2:hover, .next2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  }

.mySlides2{
  z-index: 100
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584397953202-2c15e86b09cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584269655525-c2ec535de1d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584459578334-c4ba449af8f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584381296550-99dfc0837d42?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584397953202-2c15e86b09cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>

<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides2">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584377160571-1ea5df91fc75?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=717&q=80" style="width:128px; height: 128px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides2">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:128px; height: 128px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides2">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:128px; height: 128px;">
</div>
<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next1" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>

</div> 
<div class="slideshow-container">

<!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584397953202-2c15e86b09cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px">
</div>

<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px">
</div>
<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584397953202-2c15e86b09cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px;">
</div>

<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev2" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next2" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>


</div>
```

The problem is with "mySlides2".

The next and prev button doesn't work. In all the others it does. I checked every single way. Through css, html js and chrome console. Nothing seems to pop up so i had to go here.

If you can help me i will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you can't actually click on the next & prev buttons, there is something covering them (you can click-right to inspect element either on your next or your prev button, you will notice what's on top of it).

A solution would be to change the `z-index` of your controls to a higher value, so you will have access to these.

```
.prev1, .next1{
  z-index: 10;
}
```

---

```js
var slideIndex = [1,1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 700px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.prev1, .next1 {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 7px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
  }

    .next1 {
        right: 195px;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      }
      .prev1 {
          left: 180px;
      }


      .prev1:hover, .next1:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      }
.prev2, .next2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1244px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}
.next2 {
    left: 590px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  .prev2 {
      left: 530px;
  }


  .prev2:hover, .next2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  }

.prev1, .next1{
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584397953202-2c15e86b09cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584269655525-c2ec535de1d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584459578334-c4ba449af8f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584381296550-99dfc0837d42?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides1">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584397953202-2c15e86b09cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100%; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; top: 280px;">
</div>

<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides2">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584377160571-1ea5df91fc75?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=717&q=80" style="width:128px; height: 128px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides2">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:128px; height: 128px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides2">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:128px; height: 128px;">
</div>
<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next1" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>

</div> 
<div class="slideshow-container">

<!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584397953202-2c15e86b09cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px">
</div>

<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px">
</div>
<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584397953202-2c15e86b09cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px;">
</div>
<div class="mySlides3">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584450402195-ff360cf81f30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" style="width:100px; height: 850px; border-radius: 25px; position: relative; bottom: 845px; left:530px;">
</div>

<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev2" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next2" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>


</div>
```